# TWRP: "E: Unable to mount storage" after encrypting phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, twrp

I get `E: Unable to mount storage` error in TWRP after encrypting my phone. **CyanogenMod 12.1 ROM** (based on Android 5.1.1, my phone is **HTC One M7**) in use, CM uses AOSP encryption that is supported by TWRP. TWRP doesn't work properly, I wasn't able to flash a script that used to work perfectly (no error, but flashing didn't do anything).
Should I do a wipe in TWRP? I already tried wiping the system and reinstalling ROM, no success. What partitions should I exactly wipe?

**EDIT**: I tested more and it seems that I can update my ROM and install the Xposed framework, but running scripts like freecyngn doesn't seem to work.

---

TWRP version 2.8.7.0

Comment: Doesn't TWRP ask you to enter a password to decrypt storage? Also, are you using the latest available TWRP version (2.8.7.0)?

Comment: Yes, I can access TWRP with my password. I'm using the latest version.

Comment: does changing MTP to disabled work ?